# How do I add a favorite option on my site?

Tags: javascript, html, button, favorites

I need to add a favorite button on a menu website. If the meal is favorited, it needs to be visual on the 'favorieten' button. I need to use HTML and JavaScript. The code is in Dutch, please don't worry about the names. I fixed the checkboxes on the top but I cannot get the 'hartje' (this means: heart) to respond properly and ad it to the 'Favorieten' button. Can someone help me?

This is my code:

```js
const checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
let actieve_types = []

for (let x = 0; x < checkboxes.length; x++) {
  const checkbox = checkboxes[x]

  checkbox.addEventListener("change", e => {
    if (actieve_types.includes(checkbox.value)) {
      const index_value = actieve_types.indexOf(checkbox.value)

      actieve_types.splice(index_value, 1)
    } else {
      actieve_types.push(checkbox.value)
    }

    updateView()
  })
}

const updateView = () => {
  const meals = document.getElementsByClassName("meal")

  for (let x = 0; x < meals.length; x++) {
    const meal = meals[x]

    meal.style.display = "block"

    if (actieve_types.length > 0) {
      if (!actieve_types.includes(meal.dataset.type)) {
        meal.style.display = "none"
      }
    }
  }
}

document.getElementsByClassName("hartje");.onclick = function(event) {
  for (var i = 0; i < faveMe.length; i++) {
    if (faveMe[i].className === "hartje") {
      faveMe[i].classList.replace("hartje", "welFavo");
      console.log(faveMe);
    } else {
      faveMe[i].style.visibility = "";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Menukaart_wk5/css/master.css">
  <script src="/Menukaart_wk5/js/main.js" charset="UTF-8" defer></script>
  <title>Yes!BosFood!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <section>
      <header>
        <h1>Yes!BosFood</h1>
      </header>
      <ul class="filterSection">
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="alleen">
          <label>Ik eet alleen &#124;</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="groot">
          <label>Ik wil een groot gerecht &#124;</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="delen">
          <label>Wij gaan delen</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="favo">
        <input id="eventClick" type="button" value="Favorieten">
      </div>
      <article>
        <ul id="itemsToFilter">
          <li data-type="alleen" class="meal">
            <figure><img src="/Menukaart_wk5/image/sushi_1.jpg" alt="Sushi close up"></figure>
            <h2><strong>Sushi box &#124; &euro;14.50 </strong></h2>
            <p>Keuze uit 3 grote sushisoorten en 4 kleine. Of laat je verassen door de keuze van de chef!</p>
            <button class="hartje"></button>
          </li>
          <li data-type="alleen" class="meal">
            <figure><img src="/Menukaart_wk5/image/sushi_2.jpg" alt="Vegetarische sushi"></figure>
            <h2><strong>Sushi vegabox &#124; &euro;19.50</strong></h2>
            <p>Keuze uit 3 grote sushisoorten en 4 kleine, zonder vis. Of laat je verassen door de keuze van de chef! </p>
            <button class="hartje"></button>
          </li>
          <li data-type="delen" class="meal">
            <figure><img src="/Menukaart_wk5/image/sushi_3.jpg" alt="Grote box met sushi"></figure>
            <h2><strong>Sushi box groot &#124; &euro;29.95 </strong></h2>
            <p>Keuze uit 7 grote sushisoorten en 8 kleine. Ideaal om te delen! </p>
            <button class="hartje"></button>
          </li>
          <li data-type="groot" class="meal">
            <figure><img src="/Menukaart_wk5/image/pasta_1.jpg" alt="Pasta tagliatelle"></figure>
            <h2><strong>Pasta tagliatelle &#124; &euro;12.50 </strong></h2>
            <p>Altijd lekker en dit gerecht is vegetarisch!</p>
            <button class="hartje"></button>
          </li>
          <li data-type="alleen" class="meal">
            <figure><img src="/Menukaart_wk5/image/champ_soep.jpg" alt="Champignonsoep"></figure>
            <h2><strong>Champignonsoep &#124; &euro;8.50 </strong></h2>
            <p>Heerlijk als voorgerecht en dit gerecht is vegetarisch!</p>
            <button class="hartje"></button>
          </li>
          <li data-type="groot" class="meal">
            <figure><img src="/Menukaart_wk5/image/gnocchi.jpg" alt="Gnocchi"></figure>
            <h2><strong>Gnocchi &#124; &euro;11.50</strong></h2>
            <p>Te bestellen als vega gerecht, of met vlees!</p>
            <button class="hartje"></button>
          </li>
          <li data-type="delen" class="meal">
            <figure><img src="/Menukaart_wk5/image/ei_in_saus.jpg" alt="Shakshuka"></figure>
            <h2><strong>Shakshuka &#124; vanaf &euro;8.50 </strong></h2>
            <p>Heerlijk om mee te dippen. Kies je eigen dipsoort!</p>
            <button class="hartje"></button>
          </li>
          <li data-type="delen" class="meal">
            <figure><img src="/Menukaart_wk5/image/pizza.jpg" alt="Pizza"></figure>
            <h2><strong>Pizza &#124; vanaf &euro;11.50 </strong></h2>
            <p>Stel jouw eigen pizza samen!</p>
            <button class="hartje"></button>
          </li>
          <li data-type="groot" class="meal">
            <figure><img src="/Menukaart_wk5/image/patat.jpg" alt="Patat"></figure>
            <h2><strong>Patat &#124; vanaf &euro;3.50 </strong></h2>
            <p>Stel jouw eigen patatje samen! Ga jij voor de patat met of pak je uit met een patatje oorlog?</p>
            <button class="hartje"></button>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <footer>
          <h2>Gemaakt door Simone Bos</h2>
        </footer>
      </article>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: here is typo - `document.getElementsByClassName("hartje");.onclick = function(event)`

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to let the User choose on of hte three options: 1. Ik eet alleen, 2. Ik wil een groot gerecht or 3. Wij gaan delen. And when the user then clicks on the Button "Favorieten" the selected option should be saved as chosen answer / favourite? Or you want let the user choose one of the meals (sushi box, etc)? Then you would better use a dropdown (selection) for your menues, instead of an unordered list (ul). Then combine the selection with the favorieten button in a Form.

Comment: <ul> is not really for getting user input

Comment: I have seen the typo, thank you. The user can filter trough the meals with "ik eet alleen" etc. (This means: I want to eat alone or I am sharing my food.) I want to add a heart shaped button, so they can favorite the meal. If they want to see their favorited food, they can click on the "favorieten" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try the following: In your `<ul>` you can add icons to your buttons like this:

```
<ul id="itemsToFilter">
                <li data-type="alleen" class="meal">
                    <figure><img src="/Menukaart_wk5/image/sushi_1.jpg" alt="Sushi close up"></figure>
                    <h2><strong>Sushi box &#124; &euro;14.50 </strong></h2>
                    <p>Keuze uit 3 grote sushisoorten en 4 kleine. Of laat je verassen door de keuze van de chef!</p>
                    <button class="hartje" onclick="favorizeMeal(0)"><i id="0" class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></i></button>
                </li>
                <li data-type="alleen" class="meal">
                    <figure><img src="/Menukaart_wk5/image/sushi_2.jpg" alt="Vegetarische sushi"></figure>
                    <h2><strong>Sushi vegabox &#124; &euro;19.50</strong></h2>
                    <p>Keuze uit 3 grote sushisoorten en 4 kleine, zonder vis. Of laat je verassen door de keuze van de chef! </p>
                    <button class="hartje" onclick="favorizeMeal(1)"><i id="1" class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></i></button>
                </li>
                <li data-type="delen" class="meal">
                    <figure><img src="/Menukaart_wk5/image/sushi_3.jpg" alt="Grote box met sushi"></figure>
                    <h2><strong>Sushi box groot &#124; &euro;29.95 </strong></h2>
                    <p>Keuze uit 7 grote sushisoorten en 8 kleine. Ideaal om te delen! </p>
                    <button class="hartje" onclick="favorizeMeal(2)"><i id="2" class="fa fa-heart"></i></i></button>
                </li>
                <li data-type="groot" class="meal">
                    <figure><img src="/Menukaart_wk5/image/pasta_1.jpg" alt="Pasta tagliatelle"></figure>
                    <h2><strong>Pasta tagliatelle &#124; &euro;12.50 </strong></h2>
                    <p>Altijd lekker en dit gerecht is vegetarisch!</p>
                    <button class="hartje" onclick="favorizeMeal(3)"><i id="3" class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></i></button>
                </li>
                <li data-type="alleen" class="meal">
                    <figure><img src="/Menukaart_wk5/image/champ_soep.jpg" alt="Champignonsoep"></figure>
                    <h2><strong>Champignonsoep &#124; &euro;8.50 </strong></h2>
                    <p>Heerlijk als voorgerecht en dit gerecht is vegetarisch!</p>
                    <button class="hartje" onclick="favorizeMeal(4)"><i id="4" class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></i></button>
                </li>
                <li data-type="groot" class="meal">
                    <figure><img src="/Menukaart_wk5/image/gnocchi.jpg" alt="Gnocchi"></figure>
                    <h2><strong>Gnocchi &#124; &euro;11.50</strong></h2>
                    <p>Te bestellen als vega gerecht, of met vlees!</p>
                    <button class="hartje" onclick="favorizeMeal(5)"><i id="5" class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></i></button>
                </li>
                <li data-type="delen" class="meal">
                    <figure><img src="/Menukaart_wk5/image/ei_in_saus.jpg" alt="Shakshuka"></figure>
                    <h2><strong>Shakshuka &#124; vanaf &euro;8.50 </strong></h2>
                    <p>Heerlijk om mee te dippen. Kies je eigen dipsoort!</p>
                    <button class="hartje" onclick="favorizeMeal(6)"><i id="6" class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></i></button>
                </li>
                <li data-type="delen" class="meal">
                    <figure><img src="/Menukaart_wk5/image/pizza.jpg" alt="Pizza"></figure>
                    <h2><strong>Pizza &#124; vanaf &euro;11.50 </strong></h2>
                    <p>Stel jouw eigen pizza samen!</p> 
                    <button class="hartje" onclick="favorizeMeal(7)"><i id="7" class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></i></button>
                </li>
                <li data-type="groot" class="meal">
                    <figure><img src="/Menukaart_wk5/image/patat.jpg" alt="Patat"></figure>
                    <h2><strong>Patat &#124; vanaf &euro;3.50 </strong></h2>
                    <p>Stel jouw eigen patatje samen! Ga jij voor de patat met of pak je uit met een patatje oorlog?</p>
                    <button class="hartje" onclick="favorizeMeal(8)"><i id="8" class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></i></button>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

For the icons to show up you need to add this link to the icon library I used in the head section of your html:

```
<head>
...
<!-- Add icon library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
```

There are more icon libraries, find a tutorial here: https://www.w3schools.com/icons/default.asp

Then you need to implement a logic in your Javascript that exchanges the icon class 'fa-heart' with 'fa-heart-o' if the user clicked on the button.

```
favorizeMeal(mealNumber) {
  console.log("favorizeMeal clicked for meal number: ", mealNumber);
  var selectedIcon = document.getElementById(mealNumber);
  if (selectedIcon.classList.contains('fa-heart') { 
   selectedIcon.classList.remove("fa-heart");
   selectedIcon.classList.add("fa-heart-o");
  } else {
   selectedIcon.classList.add("fa-heart");
   selectedIcon.classList.remove("fa-heart-o");
  }
}
```

Something like this (I didn't test it though!)

Comment: Is doesn't work yet but this helped a lot! Thanks!